# iOS 6 displaying update badge, no update available

Tags: ios, software-update

My app store is displaying an update as badge. When I click the App Store, it claims I have all updates.

What did Apple do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: The apps now appear to be available to download. Anyone else seeing this now too?

---

I am seeing this behaviour too and am 98% sure the updates are for for apps on your phone which require iOS7 or later.

I am not aware of a fix at this stage.

Comment: That makes sense, however they should remove the icon for me? Stupid update badge.

Comment: Yes, it's a little annoying. I think if you open up the App Store app and open the Updates page, the badges disappear (temporarily).

Comment: Updated original answer, apps now appear available for download.

Comment: I had 2 badges visible, only 1 update. So not solved (yet)